# grant select in just one DMV instead of grant VIEW SERVER STATE

Tags: sql-server

Is there some way to grant select in just one `sys.table..` for example select in `sys.dm_hadr_availability_group_states` without to grant `VIEW SERVER STATE`?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can wrap the select against the specific DMV in a stored procedure and then use Execute As to elevate the permissions.

whether you choose to sign the SP with a certificate, execute as SA or as Owner is something you will need to determine according to your own security needs.